# Simple way of using Spring RESTful API on Client?

Tags: android, spring

I was wondering if it was possible to create an API .jar for an Android App such that I am able to use it like this:

```
HelloWorldExampleAPI api;

HelloWorld helloWorld = api.getHelloWorldConnector();

helloWorld.displayMessage("How are you?");
```

Instead of having to implement `AsyncTasks` like this:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        String msg = "";
        for(String m : uri) { msg += m; }

        String url = "http://192.168.42.229:8080/HelloWorldExample/helloWorld/displayMessage/" + msg;

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        // Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response to a String
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "Android");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

From this simple servlet example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("/hello");
        model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/displayMessage/{msg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMessage(@PathVariable String msg, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("/displayMessage/{msg} : " + msg);
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

Comment: There's going to need to be a Thread or AsyncTask in there somewhere.  Could you move it into a library?  Sure.  But networking will still need to be done on another thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well yes but like you said it could be done by wrapping this thing into a library. I thought maybe there is already such a thing that does that for me. Like creating a `.jar` according to my RESTful API where I then only need to import `helloworld-api.jar` and calls like `helloWorld.displayMessage("msg");` do the rest.

Comment: There's dozens of networking libraries out there.  They all have their own flaws and pluses.  Go out and evaluate a few.  But asking for library recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not asking for library recommendations. I'm asking if I can generate a library from spring.

Comment: So you're looking for a tool.  Same thing-  tool recommendations are off topic.  Now if you were asking how to write such a tool, and had a specific question about doing so it would be on topic.

Comment: @GabeSechan No I am not. I am asking if **Spring** allows me to do that. Since I have to annotate every single function with Spring annotations I was thinking that the Spring framework will also be able to generate a client-side library for me. I am not asking for another tool or library I am asking about the capabilities of a library I am already using. However, if *there is* another tool I could use in combination with Spring my question would still not be off topic imho.

Comment: Since Spring isn't an ANdroid thing-  no, it won't.